# Как правильно писать расширенные комиты?

Tags: git, git-commit

Я только начал изучать гит - и возник вопрос:

Ка правильно писать коммиты (расширенные)

```
git commit -m 'some string'
```

это маленький коммит, а так как я пушу только 1 раз в час, то хотелось бы иметь доступ к расширенному коммиту

(видел, что некоторые (в книге было) открывают текстовый редактор и там пишут коммит)
Просто не хочется перечитывать книгу из за одной команды.

Вот как ее настроить - и как правильно писать такие коммиты (чтобы более профессиональные пользователи гит-а могли быстро понять и прочитать его).

Comment: http://digitaldreamer.net/blog/2010/4/7/setting-default-editor-git-commit-messages/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы во время коммита открылся редактор для написания сообщения, нужно просто не писать никаких сообщений в коммандной строке. Сам редактор можно изменить при помощи команды:

```
git config --global core.editor "nano"
```

Comment: во - точно!

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря в первые слышу о таком :)
Возможно вы имели ввиду это:

```
git commit
```

Появится редактор в котором вы пишите комментарий к коммиту.
или

```
git commit -a
```

что позволит без дополнительнух действий закоммитить файлы которые были изменены или удалены

Что за книга то такая?

Comment: pro git ( помню в ней было описание ) - но я читал, когда вообще не был знаком с понятием git и зачем он нужен - так что 60% тупо мимо ушей прошло